# Python: import of api module from nltk.corpus.reader

Tags: python, nlp, nltk

I am trying to import the `api` module from `nltk` package (more precisely, `nltk.corpus.reader` which has an `api` module).

When I try to do it as follows:

```
from nltk.corpus.reader import api
```

and then print what I've got, the result is

```
<module 'nltk.tokenize.api' from '/usr/lib/python2.6/site-packages/nltk/tokenize/api.pyc'>
```

So, for some reason it imports another module from another path!
Why is it at all possible and how can I fix this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> So, for some reason it imports another module wrom another path! Why is it at all possible and how can I fix this?

`from some.module import name` works for any global variable in `some.module`. In particular, `name` may be another module.

Here's a small example from stdlib:

```
>>> from os import path
>>> path
<module 'posixpath' from '/usr/lib/python2.7/posixpath.pyc'>
```

If you are on Windows then `path` might be `ntpath` module.

In your example the `reader` module probably has `from nltk.tokenize import api` in it that is why you can import the name from `nltk.corpus.reader`. There is nothing to fix except if `api` is not in `__all__` or if it is not mentioned in the docs then you shouldn't import it from the `reader` because it is not public api.